# Guide to protect .SQLITE db file in directory in application level and OS level

Tags: ios, sqlite, permissions, passwords

i am newbie,When i have to launch my application each time sqlite .db file created in below directory

```
Library/Application Support/iPhoneSimulator/6.1(example)/Applications/409235C4-9C9E-41A2-9058-FF848D2384FD(example)/Documents/name.db
```

now i want to make secure for this .db file.So i cann't add encryption process for some reasons, so i tried to set NSFilePosixPermissions but its not working for .db file.So my doubt is any further possibilities for protect .db file in application level as well as OS level such as can't copy,rwx permissions,if any one open file ask passcode,In app level also access database via passcode something like.any one guide to me.

**P.s : without encryption concepts for protection.**

Comment: You may wish to look into SQLCipher.

Comment: Is there any way to protect .db file data  without using encryption concept.can i set password for db while accessing data in app level?

Comment: see link in which you can set password of your database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To secure SQLiteDatabse in ios. you can set password of your database. see below link.

[Secure SQLiteDatabase](https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/ios-tutorial/)

Comment: thanks..Is any possible for created .db file in application set read&write permission when needed,otherwise it could be locked permanently means if any one open they can't access file .

Comment: I am using above link to set password of my Database and protect.

Comment: i,m newbie i can't understood that link can you please give to me any sample step by step to set password and another protection and configuration

Comment: when i tried those defined steps i got this error   "_sqlite3_key", referenced from:-[AppDelegate databasecreation] in AppDelegate.o and linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)